# Booting from the Ubuntu server CD doesn't start the installation process

Tags: live-cd, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on a laptop with core i5 Intel processor and 4GB of memory. I don't want any other OS on it I want to use it as my personal server.

The problem is when I boot form a CD with the .iso it just shows me a cursor in the left/top corner of the screen and the installation process doesn't begin.

I've tried burning the CD on both a PC running Ubuntu and a PC running Windows but this hasn't resolved the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the CD?  If you don't burn the .iso with a program that will create a .iso,  it will not work.

On Ubuntu, right-click your .iso and choose Open With Brasero Disc Burner.  On Windows, try using something like Daemon Tools Lite for your .iso burning needs.

Comment: On ubuntu I use k3b and in windows I use freeISOBurner